# GameCenter login controller issue on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, gamekit

I am making a universal app that uses GameKit to report achievements. This works fine when running on the iPhone - the fullscreen modal Game Center view controller slides up and asks me to log in when the app launches.

However, when I run this app on the iPad, the windowed iPad version of the GC view controller slides up, but as soon as it stops, the screen gets slightly grayed out and I cannot interact with the modal view controller or anything else.

I have narrowed the problem down to a scroll effect I am using for the application window's background, specifically when adding the animation sublayer to the window's layer:

```
-(void)startGridScroll
{
    //Create layer and pattern it with the grid image as a color
    UIImage * gridImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scrolling_grid.png"];
    UIColor * gridPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:gridImage];
    CALayer * gridLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [gridLayer setZPosition:-1];
    gridLayer.backgroundColor = gridPattern.CGColor;

    //Transform the image on its Y-axis
    gridLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    gridLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,1.0);
    CGSize scrollSize = self.window.bounds.size;

    //Make the layer's frame twice the width of the image
    gridLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, gridImage.size.width + scrollSize.width, scrollSize.height);

     //*******This is the line causing the issue******
     [self.window.layer addSublayer:gridLayer];

    //Define start position and end coordinates for grid image
    CGPoint start = CGPointZero;
    CGPoint end = CGPointMake(-gridImage.size.width, 0);
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:start];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:end];
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    //Set animation duration and begin
    animation.duration = 7.0;
    [gridLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];

}
```

I call this method twice: initially in the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, and also in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. Eliminating one call or the other doesn't help. If I comment them both out, the Game Center login view controller slides up and works fine.

I am assuming there is some sort of layer-related issue going on. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I applied the scroll effect to a new UIView's layer which I then added as a subview to the application window, rather than adding the scroll effect layer as a direct sublayer to the window. Still not sure why this behaved differently on the iPad vs the iPhone.